# What's a good approach for storing and adding various xaml controls to a UWP app (specifically NavigationView)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

**First part of my question**

I am creating a UWP app which uses the NavigationView class and need a little help as to building a good approach as to how I manage control creation in code behind (not in a markup language).

I decided as opposed to adding controls in the markup language xaml that I would create a list of controls in C# and add these control as part of my NavView_Loaded method.

I understand there are benefits to simply working with xaml to create the UI. However, I intend to have various different circumstances under which controls are visible or collapsed and I find it easier to maintain the status of controls by working in code behind or in C# using my mainpage class.

Currently, I have something like the following

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NavigationViewItem> SetNavViewItems()
    {
        var navitems = new ObservableCollection<NavigationViewItem>
        {
            new NavigationViewItem()
            {
                Content = "Home",
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Home),
                Tag = "home",
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            },
            new NavigationViewItem()
            {
                Content = "Documents",
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Document),
                Tag = "documents",
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            },
            new NavigationViewItem()
            {
                Content = "Library",
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Library),
                Tag = "library",
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            }
        };
        return navitemsHome;
    }

    private void NavView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        navitems = SetNavViewItems();

        foreach (var navitem in navitems)
        {
            NavView.MenuItems.Add(navitem);
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, in this example I have used a strongly typed collection in order to contain a collection of NavigationViewItem's. My issue here is that I wish to create a collection, list or arraylist of various types of controls (i.e. NavigationViewItemHeader, NavigationViewItem, NavigationViewList, NavigationViewItemSeparator).... and I'm not sure what is most appropriate; a list, a collection (weakly typed), an arraylist or if there is a better option.

To round out my explanation.

I then have a separate list (of strings) which contains all of the navigation item tags which I use to test conditions and set whether a corresponding control is visible or not.

**Second part of my question**

One other UI control I'm struggling with which may or may not be fully implemented as part of the NavigationView class, is expanding an Item or Header to display a list of sub items. My current understanding is that NavigationViewItem is the most appropriate control to use as the main heading/item. The sub items should be using the NavigationViewList. I can then write a method for setting the visibility of the NavigationViewList controls which is triggered when the user clicks on the corresponding NavigationViewItem.

**Third and final part**

Whenever I create a control in my NavigationView (i.e. a stack panel), it appears to automatically create a NavigationViewItem with the content stack panel which has the default style (i.e. height). I expect that this is intended and any control created in the NavigationView inherets from the NavigationViewBase. Frustratingly I seem to have difficult displaying multiple rows of a stack panel or grid which inherets from NavigationViewBase. Can anyone shed some light? Is this in my imgaination or is there something important to understand when creating a control in the NavigationView class.

Any help much appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem and I just bound the visibility of the controls with `x:Bind` and used an Event to handle the change. For the other things I also tried to achieve something similar but couldn't...

Comment: For your first question, this is pretty much why the VisualStateManager exists for XAML. Creating VisualStates (which every single platform control also uses to manage their Visual states) bound to either setters or manually called is one of the preferred ways of doing what you're wanting to do, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: you are making things complicated and hard to manage by doing everything in c#, uwp is at its best when you use xaml and you will get support easily as well.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake maybe with exception to my third question, I think you have pretty much answered my problems. I guess I got stuck in the rabbit hole of wanting to do everything in C# without investigating how I could better accomplish what I want to achieve in xaml. I'll read up about the VisualStateManager and maybe I can answer my own question.

Thanks